# Business Object Repository initialized on wrong domain

Tags: intershop

We are using Intershop 7.10.10.1 and there is strange problem we are facing regarding initialization of PostpaidPriceBORepositoryExtensionImpl (AbstractDomainRepositoryBOExtension). There are 4 application servers, and now and then method "getDomain()" from "AbstractDomainRepositoryBOExtension" just on one application server (and that problem occurs only on that app server until it's restarted) returns different domain (from another channel).
We ere initializing that repository from custom basket PLI extension (BasketPliBOA1CustomExtensionImpl) by:

```
final BusinessObjectRepositoryContext context = getContext().getVariable(BusinessObjectRepositoryContext.CURRENT);
postpaidPriceBORepository = context.getRepository(PostpaidPriceBORepositoryExtensionFactory.EXTENSION_ID);
```

This is log message with wrong domain:

```
[2019-08-22 16:55:19.082 CEST+0200] DEBUG lvpislive1.vipnet.hr ES1 appserver0 [A1-Shop-Site]  hr.a1.component.postpaid.price.capi.PostpaidPriceBORepository [] [Storefront] [U4orJF6aQTkzJQPE-Zecvq2QBdF3vzutXXB9fwIB] [3CZ1Al1erNa3mvMK-0-00] "3CZ1Al1erNa3mvMK-0-00" Calling getPostpaidPriceBO with following parameters: productID - BSsK85q6.1IAAAFpaSPwkTzN, tariffID - Ayl_AAEB068AAAFm2D5_ByXz, contractType - A, contractBinding - 24, domainID - VcwK_Slyn1kAAAFl9O1ujvEU.
```

And here with corect one:

```
[2019-08-22 16:55:19.145 CEST+0200] DEBUG lvpislive1.vipnet.hr ES1 appserver0 [A1-Shop-Site]  hr.a1.component.postpaid.price.capi.PostpaidPriceBORepository [] [Storefront] [U4orJF6aQTkzJQPE-Zecvq2QBdF3vzutXXB9fwIB] [3CZ1Al1erNa3mvMK-0-00] "3CZ1Al1erNa3mvMK-0-00" Calling getPostpaidPriceBO with following parameters: productID - BSsK85q6.1IAAAFpaSPwkTzN, tariffID - Ayl_AAEB068AAAFm2D5_ByXz, contractType - A, contractBinding - 24, domainID - aPIK_Sly.tEAAAFlWeJujvEU.
```

As you can see on first log message is domain ID from A1-Tomato-Site and strange is that request and log file is for A1-Shop-Site (different channel). Also you can see in log messages that both of them are from same session, even from same request (request ID is 3CZ1Al1erNa3mvMK-0-00).

This is code snippet from PostpaidPriceBORepositoryImpl:

```
LOGGER.debug("Calling getPostpaidPriceBO with following parameters: productID - {}, tariffID - {}, contractType - {}, contractBinding - {}, domainID - {}.",
  productID, tariffID, contractType, contractBinding, getDomain().getDomainID());
final A1PostpaidPricePO postpaidPricePO = postpaidPricePOFactory
  .getObjectByAlternateKey(new A1PostpaidPricePOAlternateKey(productID, tariffID, contractType.getName(), contractBinding, getDomain().getDomainID()));
```

Do you know what could be reason for that? Just to repeat what is strange, this is happening on only one application server (after every restart on different one, so that isn't consistent either). There is possibility if we have luck that after restart this doesn't happen on any of app servers, but after next restart problem occurs on one app server (one time we had problem on two of them from 4).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Strange indeed. I can only throw in some keywords: web adapter, session binding? A session is always glued to a site. So clearly something is not cooking there.

Comment: If you look at the WA logs. Was the first request to this application just happen to be on the a1-tomato-site channel? Must be initialing the context wronly. Also have you tried flushing the orm cache to see if it fixes the issue?

Comment: Currently this error doesn't happen on any app server, so I'm waiting for next restart to see if this will happen on any node. Then I'll continue my tests and debugging and let you know. But we tried flushing the orm cache, and this don't solve this issue, just restarting app server node helps.